# Spring Boot Oauth2 Apache Kafka - loadUserByUsername with Kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Is it possible to load user by username using Kafka message broker?

For example:
I have two applications: one for authentication and authorization, and the second application for receiving users from database. I want to create connection between these applications using Kafka message broker.

**WebSecurtyConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        kafkaTemplate.send("username", username);

        // I want to create a listener and return value here
        return null; // what should I do right here
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: have you tried creating listener?

Comment: Yes @Deadpool. But how to retrieve the value from listener data?